# Deus Ex: Mankind Divided. Cannot purchase Icarus Landing augmentation

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

I am currently at the start of M10 (*Facing the Enigma*), and I just realized that I cannot unlock the *Icarus Landing* augmentation (neither the *Descent Velocity Modulator* sub-aug). The augmentation is red and crossed-out. I'm currently at 100% System Status and have 8 Praxis points. Did I miss something? Is this a bug?

I'm playing on PS4.

[image: Augmentations menu]

Comment: Are you perhaps using experimental mods, and you disabled it to bring down your overclock percentage?

Comment: Not consciously, but I know you can do that. Do the disabled augs look like that?

Comment: Ahh, there you go.  I missed the picture; didn't load for some reason.  You put points into Remote Hacking, which is experimental.  That increased your overclock state, and you disabled the Icarus Landing system to bring it back down to 100%.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, I must have forgotten. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Koller installing the Neruoplasticity module, enabling experimental augmentations increases your overclock state.  The only way to bring down the overclocking is to disable one of your regular augmentations.  Disabling it prevents you from putting Praxis points into it, which leads to this state.

Once Koller is available to install the module, it should re-enable your Icarus Landing System, allowing you to put points into it.

Comment: It was an interesting mechanic, but I only ended up using experimental augs after getting the module in the first place. I never bothered with managing augs.